# MIcrosoft SQL Server WHERE/ CASE clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I have a where statement that depends on an id and based off the id the next where is determined. EX: if ID = 1 the where statement should be a<= 3 and b between 4 and 7 if ID <> 1 the where statement should be a<= 4 and b between 5 and 7. Not sure how to do this. Tried a `Case` clause but had no luck.

Comment: Please show us your code!

Comment: You can use `OR` and `WHERE (a.ID = 1 AND a<= 3 AND b >=4 and b<=7) OR (a.id <>1 AND a <= 4 AND b >=5 and b<=7)` should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample table in tempdb with data.

```
-- Just a test
use tempdb;
go

-- Drop table
if object_id('test') > 0
drop table test
go

-- Create table
create table test
(
    id int,
    a int,
    b int
);

-- Add data
insert into test values
(1, 3, 4),
(2, 4, 5),
(1, 4, 4),
(2, 5, 5),
(1, 3, 3),
(2, 4, 4);

-- Full table
select * from test;
```

Here is a solution using the CASE statement.

```
-- Show the data
select 
    * 
from 
    test
where
  (
    case
        when id = 1 and a <= 3 and b between 4 and 7 then 1
        when id <> 1 and a <= 4 and b between 5 and 7 then 1
        else 0
    end
  ) = 1;
```

[image]

Comment: I am glad that I could help, my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
where
  (id = 1 and a <= 3 and b between 4 and 7) or 
  (id <> 1 and a <= 4 and b between 5 and 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements you just need to parenthetical `WHERE` statements with an `OR`:

```
...
WHERE (ID = 1 AND a <= 3 AND b BETWEEN 4 AND 7)
       OR (ID <> 1 AND a<= 4 AND b BETWEEN 5 AND 7)
```